# How to restrict the production API's from external users?

Tags: api, security, azure, azure-web-app-service

I published my API application into Azure using APP Service. But I want to restrict my API’s from the external users.

I know there is an API management concept is there in Azure but it’s a big concept. and also there is an ipSecurity feature to restrict the specified IP addresses but I don't want this.

so I want simple way to restrict the external users to access my production API’s.

Can you please tell me what are the best enterprise practices for implementing the above feature?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by `outside environment`? Do you mean it should be restricted to certain users or IP addresses or something else? Please update your question with these details.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent unauthorized access to your API, you should protect the API using Azure AD and enforce users to authenticate/authorize themselves before they can access the API.

You would need to create an application in Azure AD for that. To prevent external users from accessing your API, you should make this application `single tenant`. This will ensure that only users from the Azure AD where the application is created can access the application.

Please see this link for more details on how you can accomplish this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad.

Comment: Thanks,  the above link contains API management feature but I don't want to implement API management right now because it's too big concept and there is no time for me to learn and develop complete structure of API management. so tell me simplest way to implement the above feature.

Comment: Please see if this link helps: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/.

Answer (score 1):

Depending whether your App is a B2B or B2C app, Azure has two *Identity as a Service* offer:

- [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/)
- [Azure Active Directory (B2B)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/)

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict based on IP. In App Service go to properties to find Outbound IP Addresses, for those apps you want to be able to connect to the API. Then in the web.config of the API, deny all apart from those. This can be used in addition to authentication.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">    <!-- this line blocks all apart  those listed below -->                
           <clear/> 
           <add ipAddress="xx.xx.xx.xx"/>   <!-- block an IP  -->                
           <add ipAddress="90.100.100.23" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/>   <!--block network 90.100.100.0 to 90.100.100.0-->               
        </ipSecurity>
      </security>
...
...
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, But I don't want to use ipSecurity element in web.config file because my application is B2C.

Comment: Sorry that does not make sense. Your question is to avoid "external users don’t access my API’s from outside environment " but you want it to be B2C. By definition your C in B2C means 'outside environment'

Comment: So your question is "I want to authenticate my api users how do I do that?". That's pretty vague

Comment: My question is when ever external user knows my API URL then he/she was trying to access my API URL, at that time I don't want to allow him/her to access my API even he/she knows my API URL.

Comment: Yeah authentication and authorization. It's pretty fundamental stuff. You know what Login means right?